# How to create an exe for my php based Web application?

Tags: php, exe

Now I know there are lot of questions have been asked about it.. But none of them has answers I'm looking for.. So here it is..

Let's go to the question, I have php based Web application on my local machine using wamp.. How to create a windows installer for my project?

All the answers for similar questions are having a browser inbuilt to browse the project.. I don't want like that..

For example take OrangeHRM.. They have php based app which can be installed in windows.. Now what I learnt about it is, that installer includes xampp for browsing the project.. And when you launch the app, it will open in your default browser and from there we can work on the app..

So my question is how can we make like that kind off windows installer,?

Comment: [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) would be an option

Comment: You could setup a working XAMPP Server, with your project already included in the root, and just zip the package. The user then only needs to unzip.

Comment: Have you tried digging PHAR for your purposes? You can create PHAR archive with your application and use it with builtin web-server.

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php